# telerik radgrid GridView1_ItemInserted - can I get a return value

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, telerik

I have a telerik radgrid that is doing an insert using an objectdatasource.  The insert method the objectdatasource calls has a boolean return value that I want to check in the radgrid's ItemInserted event.

Is this possible and what is the code to do it.  I checked the GridInsertedEventArgs e and there is no way I can see to get the return value but it must be there, I think I am just missing it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ItemInserted` event is better used with exceptions, hence it includes an `Exception` and `ExceptionHandled` property.

If your object data source insertion method fails (which, I trust, is what the boolean return value is intended to indicate), you should throw an `Exception` of a specific type which you can then inspect within the `ItemInserted` event.

Then depending on the type of exception, you can choose to modify the `ExceptionHandled` property and the `KeepInInsertMode` of the `Telerik.Web.UI.GridInsertedEventArgs` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Rabid's good suggestion, you can handle the `ObjectDataSource` control's `Inserted` event. This *does* allow direct access to the ReturnValue.

```
protected void myOds_Inserted(object sender, ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
   int rtrnVal = Convert.ToInt32(e.ReturnValue);
}
```

Based on the return value inspected in this event, you can throw an exception that will be handled by RadGrid in the `ItemInserted` event.

Answer (score 0):

This may help, converted from VB.net:

```
    protected void RadGrid1_InsertCommand(object source, Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs e) {
```

//Get the GridEditFormInsertItem of the RadGrid

```
GridEditFormInsertItem insertedItem = (GridEditFormInsertItem)e.Item;

//Access the textbox from the edit form template and store the values in string variables.
string CurrentCode = (insertedItem.FindControl("txtEditCurrentCode") as TextBox).Text;
```

}

Comment: If there is anything that I dont want displayed but need access to I store it in a hidden field use FindControl to get the value